# printing symbols in C

Tags: c, rows, symbols

thank you in advance for any help you may provide. I'm trying to print a board of the "+" symbols based on values given for M and N (so if it was M:3 and N:1 it would come out as +++) but I am drawing an absolute blank on how you do that. The code is in C.

Edit: To clarify. I don't remember what I need to do to print the board based on the given values. I'm well aware that if I ran this code now it would come out blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int N, M;

    printf("N: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("M: ");
    scanf("%d",&M);
    printf("\n");

    /* Show a board with N lines and M columns */


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yr gonna needs some loops, `for(...)` etc. http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-for-loop

Comment: printf("\n"); for sure will print a new line. So when you're not printing anything but a new line, how could you expect to see anything other than a new line.

Comment: The blank line is there on purpose, to space things out.

Comment: you didn't print any board so how can you expect a board to be appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get you started

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("X");
}
```

Comment: or, maybe better: `void printline(unsigned n) { while(n--) putchar('X'); putchar('\n'); }`